# How can I make a column vector?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to convert my MATLAB code to Python. In MATLAB I wrote:

```
G=[x(:).^0 x(:).^1];
```

Where `x` size is `(1,2001)` and created by

```
x=linspace(-10,10,2001)
```

`G` size is `(2001,2)` the first column is equal to 1, and the second column the value of `x`.

When I try to make the `G` matrix

```
G=np.array([[x.T**0],[x.T**1]])
```

it creates an array of size (2,1,1,2001).

I've tried

```
G=np.array((np.ones(x.size).T, x.T))
```

But that's not the way I want it. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible code snippet in python of what the arrays might look like so that we can reproduce the mathematical operation you are trying to make? Often this is a result of behavior between numpy and MATLAB. In numpy, you have specific functions to make operations such as `numpy.dot(A,B)` and `numpy.transpose(A)`

Comment: In MATLAB the trailing dimension is outer most.  In numpy it's the leading one.  So a (2,n) shape would be a natural translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While everything is MATLAB is 2d (or larger), and the trailing dimension is outer most, in `numpy` arrays can be 1d (or even 0d), and the leading dimension is outer most.

```
In [208]: x = np.linspace(-10,10,5)

In [209]: x
Out[209]: array([-10.,  -5.,   0.,   5.,  10.])     
In [210]: x.shape
Out[210]: (5,)
```

Transpose does nothing to a 1d array:

```
In [211]: x.T
Out[211]: array([-10.,  -5.,   0.,   5.,  10.])
```

`np.array` is a natural tool for combining arrays of matching size.  That's just an extension of the common demo, `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])` where the argument is a list of 2 lists.

```
In [212]: np.array((x**0, x**1))
Out[212]: 
array([[  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [-10.,  -5.,   0.,   5.,  10.]])
```

I would argue that such an array (2,n) is the natural translation of a MATLAB (n,2) matrix.

But such a array can be easily transposed:

```
In [213]: np.array((x**0, x**1)).T
Out[213]: 
array([[  1., -10.],
       [  1.,  -5.],
       [  1.,   0.],
       [  1.,   5.],
       [  1.,  10.]])
```

Or you could use `stack` with axis:

```
In [214]: np.stack((x**0, x**1), axis=1)
Out[214]: 
array([[  1., -10.],
       [  1.,  -5.],
       [  1.,   0.],
       [  1.,   5.],
       [  1.,  10.]])
```

You could make a 2d array, shape (5,1) with:

```
In [216]: x1 = x[:,None]   # or x.reshape(-1,1)

In [217]: x1
Out[217]: 
array([[-10.],
       [ -5.],
       [  0.],
       [  5.],
       [ 10.]])
```

This is closer to what MATLAB users would call a column vector.

Then concatenate those on the 2nd axis:

```
In [218]: np.hstack((x1**0, x1**1))
Out[218]: 
array([[  1., -10.],
       [  1.,  -5.],
       [  1.,   0.],
       [  1.,   5.],
       [  1.,  10.]])
```

Seems that wayward MATLAB users often have a hard time getting used to the differences (and commonalities) of (n,), (1,n) and (n,1) shaped arrays.  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Besides solving my problem you give me a clear explanation of it, which I desperately needed it.

Answer (score 2):

To make `G` you need to use [`numpy.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.linspace(-10, 10, 2001)
x0 = x1**0

G = np.vstack((x0,x1)).T
print(G.shape)
```

> (2001, 2)

Comment: or closer to what he was trying `np.array((x0,x1)).T`